# Fastforward and rewind music in XBMC

Tags: xml, customization, xbox, xbmc

As I was listening to the Stack Overflow Podcast #54 in XBMC on my XBOX I wanted to skip back a bit and hear something again.

To my chagrin the controls for seeking like in the video app weren't working. I then tried to use the seek buttons in the music OSD. No success. I next tried going to visualization mode and using the seek controls (like in video) here. Nope. As a last resort I tried the web control interface, but this didn't work either.

The XBMC forum was a mess on this topic. There were so many double posts that I couldn't find any useful information except for checking out the Keymappings.txt and Keymappings.xml files. These all look fine.

I am using XBMC 9.04r19856 (T3CH_20090521).
If anyone kan help me out it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.

It turns out this not a programming issue. 
The problem lies in the fact that I streamed via Microsoft's UPnP protocol.

The skip commands (via gamepad, OSD, and web) do work when streaming via an SMB share.